# Ubuntu 23.10 raspberrypi 5 No bluetooth found using XRDP

Tags: bluetooth, remote-desktop, raspberrypi, xrdp, 23.10

Bluetooth audio is fine locally on a RaspberryPi5. When remote from Win10 using RDP I get No Bluetooth Found, plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth.

I've tried suggestions to add user to audio, lp, plugdev and Bluetooth groups and to install pi-bluetooth but remote still sees No Bluetooth found. RDP is set to play on remote device (the RaspberryPi5). Sound from headphones using a USB dongle works OK on the remote Pi5.